# Overview of implementing Kinect and Unity 3D Integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I am looking to make a simple game project in the Unity 3D environment, that utilises the Kinect to have a game character mimic what occurs in real life. I am trying to achieve this in the shortest time possible. I am a relatively new programmer fluent in Python and with some knowledge of Java.

So I've been reading all over the internet about guides on Unity 3D, libraries like Zigfu, the Kinect, etc... But it's all scattered and presumes quite a lot of knowledge, so I was hoping someone could offer clarification.

Questions:

1. What packages are needed to achieve this (I hear terms like XNA, Zigfu, Microsoft SDK being thrown around), and what would you recommend based on the circumstances?
2. What resources are good, and where should I start. I want to try reduce redundancies (a lot of Unity tutorials cover stuff like rockets, life bars, etc that I'm not interested in). I'm a bit overwhelmed with the multitude of tutorials, and a lot of them seem very involved time-wise, and I'm just interested in getting something up as fast as possible.
3. Will I need to learn another programming language / which would be the best to use to achieve these goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried [Motion Toolkit](http://u3d.as/content/omek/omek-motion-toolkit/3CP) package from Unity asset store. It is based on Omek Beckon middleware and actually offer a sample that does exactly what you want, an avatar that is animated by movements of a person in real life.

It is implemented in C# though, but integrated very good into Unity, So I guess you'll be able to use Boo (which is Unity scripting language based on Python)